# Database in the cloud?

Tags: database, performance, cloud

Some of my recent clients are asking for remote connections to the office server, for standalone work, etc, in winForm applications.

Since the concept of the web is remote connection to a server both of data and resources, it should be possible to place both of this in cloud and have the winForm apps connect to it as if web Apps.

As any one tested this, is working like this?

Is it fast enough?

Is it secure?

What is the best cloud host for this type of work ?

Also what DB engines support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of my friends have used [MongoHQ](https://mongohq.com/home) with greate success.

Answer (score 0):

Also [Xeround](http://xeround.com) is a cloud-hosted database.  It is compatible with MySQL. I have used it before, but never for a winForm application.